# Class has not been registered after restart IIS website

Tags: c#, iis, autofac

I've created a website in IIS. Rebuild my app, it is all OK, but after restart IIS website, there is an error:

> Autofac.Core.Registration.CompoentNotRegisteredException: The registered service 'WYC.Core.Services.BlogService' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

What has happened? Why? My way:

```
container.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
         .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
         .SingleInstance()
         .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
```

Answer (score 1):

When IIS recycles the application pool, assemblies are loaded on demand. It is not recommended to use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` in IIS because all assemblies may not being loaded yet.

In order to avoid this issue, you can use the `GetReferencedAssemblies` method on the `System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager`

```
var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies();
container.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
         .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
         .SingleInstance()
         .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
```

the code above should works after a IIS recycling process.

See [Why aren’t my assemblies getting scanned after IIS restart](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/iis-restart.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you,You are great!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If the answer helps, don't forget to accept it in order to help other users. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information